# Mechanism of antiperistalsis

Tags: neuroscience, physiology, action-potential

What is the mechanism of antiperistalsis that occurs during vomiting? Why the peristaltic waves normally don't propagate in anal to oral direction? Please give logical explanation with authentic sources. :)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the mechanism of antiperistalsis that occurs during vomiting?

1. Emetic agents in the bloodstream stimulate chemoreceptors in [*area postrema*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_postrema) and [*nucleus tractus solitarius*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solitary_nucleus) [1].
2. *Nucleus tractus solitarius* is connected to motor neurons in ventral medulla and hypothalamus [1].
3. Esophageal and gastric peristalsis is inhibited. Small bowel peristalsis is reversed. Esophagus and stomach don't have antiperistaltic movements [2].

> Why the peristaltic waves normally don't propagate in anal to oral direction?

Because of the mechanism of descending inhibition. Distension of the esophagus and intestine causes a reflex action that leads to circular muscular contraction just above the bolus/chymus. Longitudinal muscle also contracts (shortens) [3].

[image]

---

Reference:

1. Hornby PJ. [Central neurocircuitry associated with emesis.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11749934) Am. J. Med. 2001 Dec 3;111 Suppl 8A:106S-112S. PubMed PMID: 11749934.
2. Brizzee KR. [Mechanics of vomiting: a minireview.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2178746) Can. J. Physiol. Pharmacol. 1990 Feb;68(2):221-9. PubMed PMID: 2178746.
3. AUMSA. *[Digestive Physiology.](http://aumsa.wikidot.com/digestive-physiology)* May 2012. CC-BY-SA-3.0